# Добавлять кнопку на каждый item в ElementTab — динамически?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void NewHolstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object newItem = new Image () ;

        ElementTab.Items.Add(newItem);


        for (int i= (int)ZeroItem.Tag; i <= ElementTab.Items.CurrentPosition; i++)
        {
            //добавлять кнопку на каждый item

        }


    }


}
```

На форме есть ElementTab  - TabControl- внутри которого добавлен Item - имя ZeroItem. Внутри этого ZeroItem - есть кнопка. Обработчик для этой кнопки приведен выше.
По нажатию на кнопку я создаю новые Items для ElementTab -добавляя их в коллекцию элементов
ZeroItem -присвоен Tag - Tag="1" который я использую в качестве счетчика

```
for (int i= (int)ZeroItem.Tag; i <= ElementTab.Items.CurrentPosition; i++)
```

- как бы привязывая его к первому элементу - там где и содержится кнопка для создания следующих Items.
Теперь в этом цикле я хочу сделать так, что бы на каждом созданном Item - также динамически - "автоматом" добавлялась кнопка.

Comment: А что такое ElementTab? TabControl что ли?

Comment: да , TabControl, сейчас подпралю

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы не совсем понимаете как работает WPF. Возможно, тут лучше подойдет помощь в чат режиме, если у вас есть некоторое время для обсуждения, предлагаю перейти в [эту чат комнату](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) - просто сделайте мне пинг когда у вас будет время